# Is it possible to quickly find citation keys by title, journal,...?

Tags: citing, article

While writing an article many times I want to reference a paper I have in my `.bib` file but I don't know its citation key even though I may know other details such as the title, the journal, one of the authors...

Is it possible to quickly find its citation key by knowing this information?

I currently go back to Mendeley every time I want to look for the citation key of the paper I'm thinking about. But this is way too slow and sometimes my thought process stops.

Comment: Have you tried the search mechanismn your editor has?

Comment: That is as slow as what I do now, that is searching in Mendeley for the citation key of the paper I'm thinking about. But I would like to know if there is a way of finding the citation key without leaving VSCode (that is where I edit my `.tex` files).

Comment: Presumably you have put all of your references into a `.bib` file.  If you use `filecontents` to include this information at the top of your source file, you can look there without leaving your editor, although you may have to leave the location in which you're currently typing.  (I don't know VSCode, and use an editor that has a two-window mode, so that would be trivial for me.)

Comment: I think the question is very clear so I don't get why it is closed. For example when you write a TeX file in TeXStudio, after typing \cite{ it starts autosuggestion, but with the label of the citations and not name of the authors, name of the paper or journal etc. One can use these labels according to these data, but you cant put everything in the label, and the autosuggestion doesn't look at the end or middle of the labels by typing the first parts which you may even forget the first parts. So I do understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need a reference manager like Mendeley or jabref to handle your *.bib file and make you able to insert the citation key from it in your editor (e.g. MS Word or TeXstudio).

I recommend you to start with [jabref](https://www.jabref.org/).

Comment: I'm currently using Mendeley and I search the citation keys there. But I was wondering if there was a faster way of finding the citation keys without leaving MS Word, TeXstudio, or VSCode in my case.

Comment: It's a function of your editor. Whenever I type \cite in Sublime, a search box pops up, allowing me to search through all quoted authors and titles with ease. Surely other editors have simular functions?